# Visual Studio code spellchecker

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, spell-checking

Is there a spell checker plugin for Visual Studio which highlights typos and badly spelled method and property names in my code? The ones I tried work only with comments.

Answer (score 1):

ReSharper, JustCode, Stylecop - all of them do code analysis. The first 2 are paid though, I think Stylecop is free (and not as powerful).

Comment: Nice. I didn't know there is a ReSharper plugin. http://blog.jetbrains.com/dotnet/2013/01/14/respeller-a-spell-checking-plugin-for-resharper/

Answer (score 1):

Visual Studio 2022 has a spellchecker since version 17.5. It was announced in [this blog post](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/visualstudio/visual-studio-spell-checker-preview-now-available/) and you can find details how to configure it [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/text-spell-checker?view=vs-2022).